# Undefined function or variable using parfor in matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm unable to execute the following code:

```
parallel_mode = true; %To process multiple images at the same time
parallel_degree = 4; %Number of threads that will be created

if parallel_mode
    if matlabpool('size') == 0
        matlabpool(parallel_degree);
    elseif matlabpool('size') ~= parallel_degree
        matlabpool close;
        matlabpool(parallel_degree);
    end    
end

%Loading dictionary
    try
        load(dictionary_path); 
    catch
        error(['Was impossible to load the dictionary in path: ' dictionary_path ', Please, check the path. ' ...
            'Maybe you should use dictionary_training function to create it.'])
    end

%% Processing test images

test_images = dir([test_im_path, pattern]);
num_test_images = size(test_images,1);

%Pre-allocating memory to speed-up
estimated_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);
true_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);

estimated_upper_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);
estimated_lower_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);
true_upper_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);
true_lower_count = zeros(1,num_test_images);

%Calculating dimensions of the image subregion where we can count
im_test = imread([test_im_path test_images(1).name]);
dis = round(patch_size/2); 
dim_x = dis:size(im_test,2)-dis+1;
dim_y = dis:size(im_test,1)-dis+1;

toGaussian = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma);

parfor a=1:num_test_images

    disp(['Processing image #' num2str(a) ' of ' num2str(num_test_images) '...']);
    im_test = imread([test_im_path test_images(a).name]);
    [~, name, extension] = fileparts(test_images(a).name);
    im_ground_truth = imread([ground_truth_path name 'dots' extension]);

    disp('Extracting features...');
    features = extract_features(im_test, features_type, dic_signal, sparsity, patch_size, mean_rem_flag);
    features = full(features); %ND-sparse arrays are not supported.

    %Re-arranging features
    features = reshape(features', size(dim_y,2), size(dim_x,2), dic_size);

    %Normalizing features
    max_factors_3D = repmat(max_factors_depth, [size(features,1), size(features,2)]);
    max_offset_3D = repmat(max_offset_depth, [size(features,1), size(features,2)]);
    features = (features-max_offset_3D)./max_factors_3D;

    %%Some stuff
    ....
end
```

When i execute it i get:

> Undefined function or variable 'dic_signal'.

when it arrives to the extract_features function. However, in the single thread version (with for instead of parfor) it works correctly.
Someone can give me any hint?.
Thank you.

EDIT:
dic_signal is defined and correctly loaded in `load(dictionary_path);`

Comment: In your code, you haven't defined `dic_signal`

Comment: I forgot to mention that dic_signal is loaded in load(dictionary_path);
I also did a step-by-step execution and dic_signal is correctly loaded.

Comment: If i substitute parfor by for, everything works

Comment: could be a problem at compilation. try placing a `dic_signal=[]` before the loading.

Comment: That was the problem. Just declaring each variable expected to be loaded as an empty matrix is all i needed to run my program. Thank you :-)
If you rewrite the comment as an answer i can mark it as the choiced answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `load` command doesn't load the variables in the workers workspace, only on your MATLAB instance workspace, which is why it works in a normal `for` loop, but not with a `parfor` loop. You might want to try instead:

```
pctRunOnAll load(dictionary_path)
```

to ensure the correct data is loaded into the workspace of each of the workers.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code, Matlab parses all variable names in the `parfor` and if it cannot determine if a variable exists, decides it must be a function and then looks for that function at runtime. So here your error saying your "function or variable" doesn't exist, really means Matlab cant find a function called `dic_signal`.

This is explained in the `parfor` docs [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html#bvlk718-1), but isn't very obvious what this means in practice - to me at least! This behaviour is not the same as for `for` loops.

A solution is to explicitly define all variables used in a `parfor` in your code. So, e.g.:

```
dic_signal = [];
load(dictionary_path)
```

So the parser knows `dic_signal` is a variable.

This happen for variables brought into the workspace with `load`, those defined in scripts called by your code, and code in unused logic branches within `parfor`.

My issue that brought me here looking for an answer was something like:

```
using_a = false;
if using_a
    a = 1;
end
parfor n = 1:5
    if using_a
        b = a;
    end
end
```

Which produces the error at runtime of:

> Unrecognized function or variable 'a'

Which can be avoided by changing to:

```
using_a = false;
a = []; % Define 'a' even though it isn't used.
if using_a
    a = 1;
end
parfor n = 1:5
    if using_a
        b = a;
    end
end
```